# OCaml - traversing a tree

Tags: tree, ocaml

Let's define a type tree in ocaml.

```
type 'a tree = 
 T of 'a * 'a list;;
```

I would like to traverse this graph on two ways: (1) from root to leaves (2) from leaves to root

Can you help me?

Comment: I think that u should replace `'a list` by `'a tree list` because what is written now is not a tree at all.

Comment: You are supposed to do your homeworks yourself, not to post them on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type 'a tree = T of 'a * 'a tree list

let rec walk_downwards f = function
  | T (elt, children) ->
      f elt;
      List.iter (walk_downwards f) children

let rec walk_upwards f = function
  | T (elt, children) ->
      List.iter (walk_upwards f) children;
      f elt
```

Comment: I think this is incompilable solution because 2ns element of tuple is _tree_ and not _list_

Comment: Yeah, copied it from the original without being careful enough - fixed.

Comment: How to it work ? Maybe you can show me traversing tree with using fold_left?